# NSTextView does not have rounded corners in spite of using setConerRadius

Tags: cocoa, nsview, rounded-corners, nstextview

I have NSTextView and need rounded corners for the same.
Hence i tried using setCornerRadius and set the value to 10, but i don't see the rounded corners in my UI.
Any ideas?

Comment: I am also interested in an answer if someone now has one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting it on the NSTextView's layer, not the NSTextView itself.

```
[[myTextView layer] setCornerRadius:10.0f];
```